# How to convert datatable to temporary table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have a code which generate different dataset each time. So, in the first loop datatable can have 2 columns ex:

Id  ||  Name

and in next loop datatable can have completely different set of columns, ex:

ProcessName  || DateOfExecution

I have to convert this datatable to SQL table but I can't predefined table structure.
Basically, is there a way to do

```
SELECT *
INTO Table 
FROM C# DataTable
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible, you need to know the column names etc. off hand. I was going to suggest dynamic sql, but even then, the created temp/table wouldn't even be available outside the scope of the dynamic call. Could you expand on what you are wanting to accomplish, there could be alternatives such as json ...

Comment: You can examine the DataTable columns and generate a CREATE TABLE statement to create the target table, and then use SqlBulkCopy to load it from the DataTable.